# Plotting csv file data to line graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, line

I have the following data in result.csv file, and I need to plot into a line graph.

```
ColA    ColB
93      46
94      56 
95      66 
97      76 
100     86
103     96
110     106
```

What I have is

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
per_data=genfromtxt('result.csv',delimiter=','
plt.xlabel ('x stuff')
plt.ylabel ('y stuff')
plt.title('my test result')
plt.show()
```

How do feed each column of data into the graph and see its trend? The size if each column will grow daily because of new data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to separate your data using a comma, to make it an actual csv. Then add the missing closing brace at the end of this line:

```
per_data=genfromtxt('result.csv',delimiter=',')
```

and plot the data using

```
plt.plot(per_data)
```

This results in this plot:
[image]

When you add more data and run the code again it should automatically appear without any change in code.

Comment: Follow up question, I need to add a column to show the date data is collected, so I want to graph everything EXCEPT the first column. Can I iterate through the csv file object and skip the first column?

Answer (score 4):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

from numpy import genfromtxt

data = genfromtxt('example2.csv',delimiter=' ')

plt.plot(data)

plt.title('Epic Info')
plt.ylabel('Y axis')
plt.xlabel('X axis')

plt.show()
```

The above code generated this :: [image]

Comment: Upvoted because this uses the original question's data as-is.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = np.genfromtxt('path_to_data', delimiter=',', names=['x', 'y'])
plt.plot(data['x'], data['y'])
plt.show()
```

That's it.